# Rails console executing a stale copy of the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a strange issue with rails console. In fact, I am modifying the code of class function (static class).

```
class SomethingWorker
  @queue = :resque_queue

  def self.perform(method, *args)
    send(method, *args)
  end

  def self.async(method, *args)
   Resque.enqueue(SomethingWorker, method, *args)
  end

  def self.process_data
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

Sometimes, when I change the function code. It contain to execute stale (old) code. Even restarting rails console doesn't solve the issue.

I verified that the files were saved and killed all the ruby processes.

PS. the `self.process_data` isn't queued and I am just calling it from rails console:

```
SomethingWorker.process_data.
```

I discard any issue with resque (not running) and redis (down)

Comment: If you are using redis did you make sure that was shut down to? They get queued up and if they aren't queued in rails itself, say redis they are stored there even after a reset so they still run they next time they can. Oh wait my bad it is still running the old code is odd.

Comment: Try restarting resque and clearing the queues. *PS* this should not affect the rails console but the jobs which are queued. give it a try

Comment: I am running the code without queuing it and Redis is shutdown

Comment: ap File.open("./app/workers/something_worker.rb").read run under rails c shows the new modifications

Comment: Are you using `spring` or `zeus`?

Comment: Just to be safe try `spring stop` before you restart the console, I personally just remove this gem

Answer (score 1):

```
spring stop
```

Solved the issue and rails console is running the latest code.

Comment: what does it do?